# Setting ID to identify checkbox uniquely

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developer an Android 3.1 and above application.

I'm developer a dynamic form generator, and I need to add programatically a lot of check boxes.

Forms will be tables with a question on their first column, and the others columns will have check boxes.

This is a piece of code where I add check boxes:

```
int optionsTotalNum = this.calculateColumsForBlock(block);
            QuestionsGroup qGroup = block.getQuestionsGroup();
            for(int z = 0; z < qGroup.getQuestions().size(); z++)
            {
                tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                Question q = qGroup.getQuestions().get(new Integer(z));
                params = new LayoutParams(this.optionWidth, this.rowHeight);
                params.column = 0;

                TextView optionName = new TextView(this);
                optionName.setText(q.getQuestionText().toUpperCase());
                optionName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                optionName.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(optionName);

                for (int index = 1; i < optionsTotalNum; i++)
                {
                    params.column = index;
                    CheckBox check = new CheckBox(this);

                    int id = ((z + 1) * 100) + index;
                    check.setId(id);
                    check.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tableRow.addView(check);
                }
                table.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        this.rowHeight));
            }
```

I use `int id = ((z + 1) * 100) + index;` to create ids dynamically but I'm not sure if I will repeat and Id. In other words, I'm not sure if I will have two views with the same ids. I know that all check boxes will have different IDs, but I will have `TextViews`, and a `TableLayout` and `TableRows` and I don't know if they could have an ID that is used on a `CheckBox`.

What happen with `findViewById()` if there are two views with the same ID?
Can we have two or more views with the same ID on a same ContentView?
Is there any better method to identify all check boxes uniquely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are adding it at runtime.. you don't have to set an id.. you can keep all of them in some Collection which maintains insertion order and access them directly... 
 if you want to continue with same idea.. then don't do any complex stuff here.. just keep a **static counter** at class level.. set it as id and then increment it...

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. If I create a collection with those check boxes, I will only store references to those check boxes, isn't it? I will not create more. Sorry but my memory management knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unique ids, simply use 
    int id = (int) java.util.Date().getTime() 
This function will return current date and time in miliseconds and is always unique.
Save this id in an array (or another container) for further references.